# Finding nearest non-coprime number

Tags: java, algorithm

Given an array, I need to find the indices of nearest non-coprime number (i.e. GCD(Ai, Aj) > 1 , for any Ai and Aj in the array, i != j ) Example, let the array be

```
[2 17 4 6 10]
```

The answer will be

```
[3 -1 4 3 4]
```

I've written this brute force code (which is O(n^2)) using Binary GCD method, which is not very efficient. I'm wondering if there's a faster way to do this. **Particularly in O(NlogN)**

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * Built using CHelper plug-in
 * Actual solution is at the top
 *
 * @author Mayur Kulkarni
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream inputStream = System.in;
        OutputStream outputStream = System.out;
        BladeReader in = new BladeReader(inputStream);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
        GCDPuz solver = new GCDPuz();
        solver.solve(1, in, out);
        out.close();
    }

    static class GCDPuz {
        public static int gcd(int p, int q) {
            if (q == 0) return p;
            if (p == 0) return q;
            // p and q even
            if ((p & 1) == 0 && (q & 1) == 0) return gcd(p >> 1, q >> 1) << 1;
                // p is even, q is odd
            else if ((p & 1) == 0) return gcd(p >> 1, q);
                // p is odd, q is even
            else if ((q & 1) == 0) return gcd(p, q >> 1);
                // p and q odd, p >= q
            else if (p >= q) return gcd((p - q) >> 1, q);
                // p and q odd, p < q
            else return gcd(p, (q - p) >> 1);
        }

        public int coprime(int p, int q) {
            if (p % 2 == 0 && q % 2 == 0) {
                return 2;
            } else if (p == q + 1 || q == p + 1) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return gcd(p, q);
            }
        }

        public void solve(int testNumber, BladeReader in, PrintWriter out) {
            int size = in.nextInt();
            int[] arr = in.readIntArray(size);
            int[] ans = new int[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (arr[i] == 1) {
                    ans[i] = -1;
                    continue;
                }
                int left = i == 0 ? -1 : findLeft(arr, i);
                int right = i == arr.length - 1 ? -1 : findRight(arr, i);
                int leftDist = left == -1 ? -1 : i - left;
                int rightDist = right == -1 ? -1 : right - i;
                int anss = findNearestIndex(left, leftDist, right, rightDist);
                ans[i] = anss == -1 ? -1 : anss + 1;
            }
            printa(ans, out);
        }

        private void printa(int[] ans, PrintWriter out) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int an : ans) {
                sb.append(an).append(" ");
            }
            out.println(sb.toString());
        }

        private int findRight(int[] arr, int i) {
            if (arr[i] == -1) return -1;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (coprime(arr[i], arr[j]) > 1) return j;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        private int findLeft(int[] arr, int i) {
            if (arr[i] == -1) return -1;
            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                if (coprime(arr[i], arr[j]) > 1) return j;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        private int findNearestIndex(int one, int oneDist, int two, int twoDist) {
            if (oneDist == -1 && twoDist == -1) return -1;
            if (oneDist == -1) return two;
            if (twoDist == -1) return one;
            if (oneDist == twoDist) {
                return Math.min(one, two);
            }
            return oneDist < twoDist ? one : two;
        }
    }

    static class BladeReader {
        public BufferedReader reader;
        public StringTokenizer tokenizer;

        public BladeReader(InputStream stream) {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream), 32768);
            tokenizer = null;
        }

        public String next() {
            while (tokenizer == null || !tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                try {
                    tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
            return tokenizer.nextToken();
        }

        public int nextInt() {
            return Integer.parseInt(next());
        }

        public int[] readIntArray(int size) {
            int[] array = new int[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                array[i] = nextInt();
            }
            return array;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se]

Comment: @JimGarrison It is tagged algorithm as well, it's not only the code that the OP wants advice on.

Comment: The OP has provided example code - which we ask people to do - but the question is one about algorithms, not about the code.  Can we make use of the fact that if gcd(a,b *c) > 1 if gcd(a,b)>1 or gcd(a,c) > 1? I have heard of this trick being used in factorisation algorithms, but looking at the numbers I don't see how it can pay off here - the cost of the gcd seems to rise too quickly as the number of digits in the numbers to be factorised increases. If I am wrong, it might help to produce a binary tree in which the number at the nodes is the product of all the numbers in the leaves below it.

Comment: @JimGarrison While I agree that this question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow, it would be more informative to pick a closure reason that is actually stated in the [help/on-topic] and that explains _why_ it is not appropriate for Stack Overflow. (Namely, that asking for performance improvement is not a specific problem to be solved.)

Comment: @mcdowella If I produce such a tree where I calculate the products before every index, wouldn't that number grow very quickly? I'm not very good at number theory, but if I mod it with a prime number, will it preserve the information?

Comment: @Mayur you would expect as many digits in the product as the sum of the numbers multiplied together, which is one reason why I can't get the numbers to work - multiplication itself will become expensive. I think modding with a prime will destroy the information you need.

Comment: @MayurKulkarni Just from curiosity, what site did you pick this problem from?

Comment: @MayurKulkarni I looked over your (deleted now) code - the factorisation method is suboptimal. Since you start with `d=2`, the minimal code modification would be to replace `++d` with `d += (2==d ? 1 : 2)`. This way: first pass through the factorisation cycle, you eat away any power of 2; the next steps you'll keep testing only against even divisors.

Answer (score 2):

If you know your max value for your numbers and can afford to keep a list of primes, then factoring them may be a better solution **for the average/random case**. Otherwise, worst case complexity, it's still O(N*N) - think "all of them are primes" for the worst case.

Approach:

- factor them and store a `Map<prime, multiplicity>[N]` + `int closestNeigh[]`
- take a factor and `O(N)` determine for each of them the closest that contain that factor (prefix/sufix sums will be involved)
- eliminate that factor from all the factor maps
- take the next factor. Adjust the closest neighbor index only if new one is closest.

This may bring some "relief" on the line of `O(N*<num_distict_factors>)`, but again if `<num_distict_factors> == N` (all primes), then it is still O(N*N)

Comment: I came up with a similar approach, where I maintained N lists of indices, where N are the prime numbers (1 list for every prime). Then for every index, I binary searched the closest index in X lists (lists which are present in prime factorization of current number)but it still is slow.

Comment: @MayurKulkarni "but it still is slow." as I said, I believe the worst case scenario is still O(N*N).

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to get into factorization, one could traverse the list, once from the left, factoring each number, hashing the index of each new prime (with the prime as the key), updating the index of each prime already seen, and, of course, noting the nearest seen prime. Since this traversal would miss the nearest on the right, conduct another traversal from the right to update any nearer shared prime, using the factor lists already saved.